# codeigniter using foreach 2 times

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I have a view file that uses a foreach 2 times, the first time works but the second foreach doesnt do anything.

```
<?php

echo '<table><tr>'; #begin table

foreach ($query->list_fields() as $field) {  #generate table headers
printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $field);
 }
print('<th> </th></tr>'); #exra whitespace and end table row
print('<tr>'); # start new row for table data

foreach ($query->list_fields() as $data) {  #generate table data
printf("<td>%s</td>\n", $data);
}
print('</tr></table>');
```

so the tableheaders ar shown see the sourcecode:

[image: See highlighted area]

how can I arrange that the second foreach is going to work?
I'm a newbe here :-)

Comment: After your first loop the internal pointer has already reached the end of `list_fields()` items. Reset it before the second loop.

Comment: Once you looped over all results of a database query, trying to fetch another record will return only false – that’s how it’s designed, and why looping over database results in such a manner works in the first place. Either put the results into an array that you can loop over multiple times, or reset the query pointer before the second loop (the first one will usually be better for performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going along with what the comments have said, this is the solution:

```
$my_data = $query->list_fields();
foreach($my_data as $field) {  #generate table headers
   printf("<th>%s</th>\n", $field);
}
foreach ($my_data as $data) {  #generate table data
    printf("<td>%s</td>\n", $data);
}
```

Comment: yes thank you that was the solution, now I can use the double foreach.
problem is not solved yet but i'll post a new topic about how to get the data in it